# Understanding Nutanix features

Tags: cloud-computing, nutanix

From a *very* high level view:

- Open Stack is sort of framework to manage your cloud but you need to implement things
- Cloud Stack / Cloud Shift / Rancher are more or less solutions to get your cloud running but less customizable

Then, where does Nutanix go? Is it unique through extended storage support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nutanix is proprietary Software-Defined Storage stack (NDFS, Nutanix Distrubuted File System) which is nothing but NFS/SMB3 gateway built on top of Java-written Cassandra DB, + open-source derived Prism UI for management, + performance and backup-specific (CBT-bases snapshots for integration with Veeam backup etc). In a nutshell: nothing unique :)

Comment: thanks :-) phew, quite astonishing to learn more about technology behind a unicorn.
Regarding proprietary, it has also a community edition, right?

Comment: Yup. Community edition is stripped down in terms of performance, but functionality is more or less the same. In general see: http://www.cultofanarchy.org/perfomance-test-nutanix-4-node-cluste/